# Amazon API Gateway Unsupported Media Type

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, bucket

Making an API Gateway call for a S3 Bucket following AWS documentation returns this error. The bucket contains all .jpeg type files.

[image]

I've already changed the content handling and the mapping templates but it doesn't seem to work (or I'm doing something wrong).

I'm not using any other Amazon service (I'm pretty new to this technologies) and haven't found any information.

Final goal would be to **download** the file when the API is called so how should I implement it?